# MATLAB for hybrid blind equalization algorithm by JC Lin

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am doing MATLAB simulation for hybrid blind equalization algorithm. Referring to the paper titled "Blind equalisation technique based on an improved
constant modulus adaptive algorithm" by J-C Lin, I have done the programming in MATLAB based on:

[Tap weight vector update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9wyk.jpg)

The confidence zone for real and imaginary are from paper "New blind equalization techniques based on constant modulus algorithm" by Oh and Chin which I have simulated and the result is correct.

I suspect the wrong for this algorithm is at the normalized input vector in the denominator of step size. My coding is:

```
    norm_X = transpose(X)*X+10^(-7);
    w = w - (mu / (norm_X)^2) * X * conj(ehat_real + j*ehat_imag);`
```

Can anyone help me? I can provide any details about programming if it is necessary.